# Why set num_batch_threads to number CPU cores with GPU setup

Tags: gpu, tensorflow-serving

With Tensorflow Serving, the recommendation for batching parameters for GPU inference is to set `num_batch_threads`to the # of CPU cores  https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/batching/README.md#gpu-one-approach. However, experimentally, I've seen that setting `num_batch_threads=1` has produced lower latencies at lower rps (i.e. 200). I'm using a 12 cores of CPU and 1 V100 GPU. I wanted to understand why this recommendation was made and how to choose a good value for this parameter.

Comment: It might be better to direct this question to the TensorFlow Servings team: https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues

Comment: Thanks! I started to but the issue template made it seem like the question didn't fall under something that could be reported as an as there are already docs and it isn't a bug... I ended up getting a little support from google support, but they essentially said to set it to what works best for you after experimentation :)

Comment: Just add it to the set of a million hyperparameters we can tune. :D